# Control haptic engine and force touch from terminal

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, trackpad

Is there any way that I can create haptic feedback with the integrated force touch trackpad on my rMBP using a terminal command (preferably without AppleScript, but if that's the only way, then sure.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple hasn't released an API for that, so the answer until someone reverse engineers it (or Apple releases an API) is no.

The best you can do today is read force touch but not influence the haptic feedback or modify that.

- https://developer.apple.com/osx/force-touch/