# Disable Force Touch from terminal using Bash or AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, bash, trackpad

Is there a way to disable (or do other things to) the Force Touch settings using either shell scripting or AppleScript?  Hacks accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Credit:[Control haptic engine and force touch from terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228908/control-haptic-engine-and-force-touch-from-terminal)
@bmike

> Apple hasn't released an API for that, so the answer until someone
>   reverse engineers it (or Apple releases an API) is no.
>
> The best you can do today is read force touch but not influence the
>   haptic feedback or modify that.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/osx/force-touch/

Answer (score 1):

Please use the command listed below. As of 10.13 its a global preference.

Path of Preference:
global preference in user preference folder

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.forceClick -bool false
```

Just take the command and add it to your bash or Apple Script.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not appear to work on my Mac. I found an alternative, `com.apple.trackpad.forceClick`, but I haven't been able to make this work yet either.

Comment: Works for me with the alternative only.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't been able to adjust the haptic feedback settings directly, I have been able to disable the "Lookup & Data Detectors" setting, which is what causes those annoying dictionary pop up suggestions.

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.forceClick -bool false
```